# C# Gecko Browser Drop Event Simulation

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, openfiledialog, gecko

I want to simulate drop event in my code on an outside control.
I am using a Gecko browser which connects to outside web application, which code I don't have access to.

I was thinking about two solutions to this, the first would be to simulate drop event providing a filepath, however what I did below is not working:

```
 GeckoNode dropbox = ContentFrame.GetContentDocument().GetElementsByClassName("filepicker dropzone dz-clickable").FirstOrDefault();

 if (NodeType.Element == dropbox.NodeType)
            {
                DependencyObject fakeobject = Application.Current.Windows[0] as DependencyObject;
                GeckoHtmlElement drop2 = dropbox as GeckoHtmlElement;
                drop2.Focus();
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(fakeobject, path, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
```

The element which I can drop files into, on mouse click opens the "open file dialog".
The second, probably harder solution would be to somehow capture the dialog box and paste my path into it. 
Or maybe there is a way to make my code still running independently of dialog box that appears and use SendKeys or something like that?

Thank you in advance for your help! (Two days of googling didn't bring me any useful results..)

Edit:
As there were no answers, maybe anyone could answer a simpler question:
How to simulate the drop event just in WPF/WinForms? What are the steps and declarations prior to use DoDragDrop (or similar) interface? I am trying to drop a file on a droppable control (simulated in C# code) on an external Website.
Thank you!